# improving the speed of the execution of that piece of code

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, optimization

I have two methods used to render a grid. First one :

```
void Grid::openglRender(){
  glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  Node* A, * B, * C, * D;
  for(size_t X=0 ; X<sizeX-1 ; X++)for(size_t Z=0 ; Z<sizeZ-1; Z++){
    A = &nodes[X*sizeZ+Z];
    B = &nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+Z];
    C = &nodes[X*sizeZ+(Z+1)];
    D = &nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+(Z+1)];
    glVertex3f(A->x, A->y, A->z);
    glVertex3f(B->x, B->y, B->z);
    glVertex3f(C->x, C->y, C->z);

    glVertex3f(B->x, B->y, B->z);
    glVertex3f(D->x, D->y, D->z);
    glVertex3f(C->x, C->y, C->z);
  }
  glEnd();
};
```

Second one :

```
void Grid::openglRender(){
  glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  for(size_t X=0 ; X<sizeX-1 ; X++)for(size_t Z=0 ; Z<sizeZ-1; Z++){
    glVertex3f(nodes[X*sizeZ+Z].x, nodes[X*sizeZ+Z].y, nodes[X*sizeZ+Z].z);
    glVertex3f(nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+Z].x, nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+Z].y, nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+Z].z);
    glVertex3f(nodes[X*sizeZ+(Z+1)].x, nodes[X*sizeZ+(Z+1)].y, nodes[X*sizeZ+(Z+1)].z);

    glVertex3f(nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+Z].x, nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+Z].y, nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+Z].z);
    glVertex3f(nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+(Z+1)].x, nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+(Z+1)].y, nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+(Z+1)].z);
    glVertex3f(nodes[X*sizeZ+(Z+1)].x, nodes[X*sizeZ+(Z+1)].y, nodes[X*sizeZ+(Z+1)].z);
  }
  glEnd();
};
```

for me the first one looks better in term of number of operations, in `glVertex3f` I just use the pointer to get a value. In the second method each time I have to multiply and to add something.

But at the running time I don't realy feel a difference. So I'm right when I say that the first one is better ? or maybe whatever I chose the compiler know better than I, what to do to get the best...

maybe it would be a bit better if I declare `X` and `Z` before the `for` loops to avoid especially the declaration and destruction `sizeX` times of Z

Also I guess, the best would be to create a list (one time, stored ro be reused every frame) with all nodes in the order to be traversed to create the grid instead of using two `for`

Comment: Chances are good that the call overhead of `glVertex3f (...)` ***far*** exceeds any fancy pants pointer arithmetic hacks you can throw at this problem. There is literally no point in micro-optimizing immediate mode like this, you should switch to indexed vertex arrays and call it time better spent. But if you insist, you can make this nightmare last longer if you throw `glVertex3fv (...
)` into the mix for yet another micro-optimization.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman sounds good, to be honnest I never used vertex array, so I even didn't thought of it when I wrote that code. I read few about them in some book. I will read more about that at the library tomorow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = &nodes[X*sizeZ+Z];
B = &nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+Z];
C = &nodes[X*sizeZ+(Z+1)];
D = &nodes[(X+1)*sizeZ+(Z+1)];
```

could be

```
A = &nodes[X * sizeZ + Z];
B = A + sizeZ;
C = A + 1;
D = B + 1;
```

which should not only reduce the number of operations quite a bit, but would also make the relationship of the nodes a bit more obvious.  I don't know how smart your compiler is, and whether it'd be able to do that kind of optimization itself.  But why make it have to, when the alternative is clearer?

(Obligatory warning about premature optimization here.  If you're not even noticing a difference between the two, then it's too early to worry about micro-optimizing.)

Comment: I like that I will reuse this

Answer (score 0):

Just because you optimize a piece of code doesn't always mean that you will see better runtime performance. How are you measuring the runtime performance? Depending on the number of iterations within the two for loops, you may not ever see a difference unless the number of iterations is high enough. What is the actual value of sizeX and sizeZ?

Comment: Actualy my aim is to gain some tips to write more efficiently. I'm not measuring runtime.

Comment: While it is always a good thing to make sure you're writing clean and efficient code, be careful to not fall into the trap of "premature optimization" -- which means making all kinds of code optimizations without really even needing to do so. It can actually make the code become less clear to others in some cases depending on what sort of optimizations you make.

Comment: yes, I already waste some time trying to get something better. I always try to remind what an old teacher told me when I was young :« the best is the ennemy of the good » (translated from french)

Answer (score 0):

Those calls is deprecated, that's one reason why your program is running slow. You should look into VBO and shaders instead!

Comment: I'm reading the orange book (shaders) but I don't really understand what should be written in shader and what should be written in C++, I know that shader use GPU, so I ask myself if everything related to graphics should be written in shader.

Comment: @bobthemightyspellcaster: No, only things that are used for dynamic computation belong in shaders. There are a lot of operations that still need to be done only once at load-time. I would strongly suggest you study the stages of the OpenGL pipeline before jumping into shaders - shaders are actually miniature programs that run on the GPU and compute the output for certain stages of the pipeline (e.g. Vertex transform stage = vertex shader, primitive assembly stage = geometry shader, rasterization stage = fragment shader). Once you understand the flow of the pipeline, shaders make more sense.

Comment: @bobthemightyspellcaster: Have a look at [this article](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview) for more details.